# Windows Identity Foundation - Same Issuer For Different Realms

Tags: .net, wif, claims-based-identity

Is it possible for 2 websites with 2 different domains/realms to use the same issuer? If so, am I correct to assume that a trust would not need to be created between these 2 realms since they use the same issuer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two realms can certainly trust the same issuer. Whether those two need to trust each other depends on whether or not you'll need to broker trust between them. For example, assume the issuer is a big, well-known bank of your choice. The first website provides check reordering capabilities. The second allows for payments to be made. The bank wants to use both of these sites, so they trust the bank to issue identity claims. The payment processor need not trust the check reorderer and vise versa. HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now that I think about how WIF is implemented, it makes perfect sense. If a million sites used the same issuer and all made request to one another's websites, they'd all be valid requests since the tokens all came from the exact same issuer. The token would pass validation every time because the digital signature would always match.

Comment: I have one more question. How would you implement a scenario where you want to lock a user out of his/her account after n number of invalid logins. Normally Membership API encapsulates this, but by handing off authentication to WIF, it's not exactly trivial where you'd plug this logic in. Would you have to implement you own STS? Or is their some way to get notified of this type of event by ADFS? I'm sure there has to be an extensibility point somewhere.

Comment: Antwan - a system that relies on an issuer has little control on how the issuer authenticates users or what rules it applies. That's the whole point of this approach in fact. Locking a user out after x number of attempts is the responsibility of the Identity Provider (the token issuer). If you want to control this, then you need to provide your own issuer. ADFS in particular relies on AD for authentication. Whatever you configure in AD would apply to ADFS. If the user is locked, then no token wil be issued for the app. Makes sense?